# Unable to remove elements from a array

Tags: javascript

I have a Array , i am trying to remove all the eleemnts from the array , whose id is greater than myid value

i have tried as shown

Even tried with using parseFloat

Comment: Just exchange `>` with `<=`

Answer (score 1):

You should inverse your condition. If you return `true` from the filter's callback - elements will be kept.

```
var new_arr = myarray.filter(function(x) {
    return  parseInt(x.id) <= parseInt(myid) ;
});
```

And some cleaner (ES6) code:

```
const new_arr = myarray.filter(x => (+x.id <= +myid));
```